# Laravel 5: sharing a "application logic model" folder between projects

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Hello Laravel Developer,

I am really stressed by keeping the logic model of my laravel projects equal, and you could help me out:

Here's the Context:

- I got 4 different laravel (v5.3) projects
- All projects are using a bunch of classes, that i call the 'logic model'
- All projects are implementing this logic model redundant in all 4 projects
- keeping these logic models equal is stressful while developing

Here's the Question:

- How can I use laravel to include a "shared" [folder of classes | seperate laravel project] tp_logic_model, so development will end up with a folder structure like this:

[image]

while all projects include the implemented classes in the tp_logic_model folder.

I am using composer to manage external packages, but i do not want to host a new composer package to share the logic.

Is there an easy way to achieve this behaviour?

- I hope you get the idea behind my needs.
- Of cause this is a development comfort problem, but its easy to understand and maybe people are interested.

Comment: You could make it into a composer package.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a perfect case for package. Why the objection to a package, though? It's literally one repository, a few lines in your composer.json and you're set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these four projects are on the same server. The easiest way to achieve this is probably through a symbolic link.

Let's say you keep the shared logic codes on `project1` at `/var/www/project1/tp_logic_model`. To share it on `project2`, you can simply create a symbolic link to the shared logic codes within the `project2` directory:

```
ln -sfv /var/www/project1/tp_logic_model /var/www/project2/tp_logic_model
```

You can still configure the `composer.json` on each project to autoload the classes within the `tp_logic_model` directory, even if it's actually just a symbolic link.

```
// composer.json on project2, autoload from symbolic link
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Shared\\": "tp_logic_model"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use git submodules?

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: this seems to be pretty much work :o maybe there is an easier way